# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to log out

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm making a simple app using Vue.js and vue router. I'm getting this error when trying to log out of my app:

```
vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2827 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at RegExp.[Symbol.match] (<anonymous>)
    at String.match (<anonymous>)
    at matchRoute (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1636)
    at match (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1518)
    at redirect (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1578)
    at _createRoute (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1617)
    at match (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1519)
    at redirect (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1578)
    at _createRoute (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1617)
replace @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2827
logout @ App.vue?234e:64
click @ App.vue?4de4:34
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
3
```

Here's my router.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
import Login from "./views/Login.vue";

import auth from "./auth";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "home",
      component: Home,
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "login",
      component: Login,
      redirect: () => {
        if (auth.loggedIn()) return "/dashboard";
        else return "/";
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/users",
      name: "users",
      component: () => import("./views/Users.vue"),
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    },
    {
      path: "/plans",
      name: "plans",
      component: () => import("./views/Plans.vue"),
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    },
    {
      path: "/meetups",
      name: "meetups",
      component: () => import("./views/Meetups.vue"),
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    },
    {
      path: "/notif",
      name: "notifications",
      component: () => import("./views/Notifications.vue"),
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    },
    {
      path: "/admins",
      name: "admins",
      component: () => import("./views/Admins.vue"),
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      component: () => import("./views/About.vue"),
      beforeEnter: requireAuth
    }
  ]
});

function requireAuth(to, from, next) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    next({
      path: "/login",
      query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

Here's my logout function:

```
logout() {
      auth.logout();
      this.$router.replace("/");
    }
```

The app is a simple dashboard for showing some stats. I'm using a custom auth using firebase etch. It was working earlier I don't know what i did to breakt it pls help!
**Update** I get another error when using code suggested in error, not sure what this error is about:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"3092cd10-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90& (app.js:1116), <anonymous>:30:55)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925)
```

Comment: I think you're just getting redirected to login again and again. Try to use a meta and specify requiresAuth for routes and keep this as not required for login page. Let me know if you need any further help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you logged out, `auth.loggedIn()` will return `false`.

So in `redirect` property of login route, `else` part execute. And you redirect to login page again, and then `redirect` execute again and again. and in an infinite loop you are redirecting to login page.

You have to check and not run redirect function if you are redirecting to login page. You can use `beforeEnter` like other routes:

```
function checkLogin(to, from, next) {
  if (auth.loggedIn()) {
    next({
      path: "/dashboard",
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

and in routes array:

```
routes: [
    ...
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "login",
      component: Login,
      beforeEnter: checkLogin
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I get another error using your code, check updated question.

Comment: Also getting this warning: `[vue-router] invalid redirect option: undefined`

Comment: I think there is no option to continue on rendering route in `redirect`. Would you text `beforeEnter` ?

Comment: Should i check the condition in before enter, then redirect? How do I do that, can u show me some code?